# How to Distinguish between mounted volume and image native directory in Docker

Tags: c#, linux, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core

If I mount a volume in **docker**

```
docker run -v /folder1:/folder1 [imageid]
```

Is there a way in **code** to tell **/folder1** is a mounted volume and not an image native folder?

Like

```
new DirectoryInfo("/folder1")
```

Comment: In short: no. The idea is that docker's OS will map that directory for you, at a lower level that .NET Core (or any other application framework) can see.

Comment: I know of at least 2 workarounds.
1) check if my directory is on System.IO.Directory.GetLogicalDrives()
2) use df (same as above pretty much)

Comment: I guess it's a qustion of - can .net figure out a mount vs physical directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familar with C#, but if you can access file under `/proc`, you can check file `/proc/self/mountinfo`.

If a dir is from image itself, it is mount as `overlay`.

If a dir is create at runtime, it is mount as `proc | tmpfs | sysfs | devpts | mqueue | cgroup`.

If we exclude these mount type, the rest of lines in `/proc/self/mountinfo` will be the volume you mount. In short, this command works in my situation:

```
cat /proc/self/mountinfo | grep -v 'proc\|tmpfs\|sysfs\|devpts\|mqueue\|cgroup\|overlay'
```

Comment: I seriously doubt this is exposed anywhere in .net so I guess this is as good an answer as I'm ever gonna get :o
I can work with it. thx

Answer (score 0):

found in Microsoft's github repository:

https://github.com/aspnet/DataProtection/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection/Internal/DockerUtils.cs